# Elasticsearch: upsert working on older version but not on newer version

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an upsert query running in bulk. Final document is to be stored like this:

```
{
  "email": "abc@xyz.com",
  "sources": [1,2]
}
```

Here is the code:

```
var doc = {
  "source": parseInt(id),
  "email": email
}

var upsert_query = {
  "script": "if (ctx._source.containsKey(\"sources\")) { if (!ctx._source.sources.contains(source)) { ctx._source.sources += source; } } else {ctx._source.sources = [source] }",
  "params": {
    "source": doc.source
  },
  "upsert": {
    "email": doc.email,
    "sources": [doc.source]
  }
}

bulkRequestBody.push({"update": {"_index": "my_index", "_type": "email", "_id": doc.email, "_retry_on_conflict": 3}});
bulkRequestBody.push(upsert_query);
```

The code works perfectly fine on elasticsearch version 1.4 but not working on version 2.1.1.

I also tried to restructure my query:

```
var upsert_query = {
  "script": {
    "inline": "if (ctx._source.containsKey(\"sources\")) { if (!ctx._source.sources.contains(source)) { ctx._source.sources += source; } } else {ctx._source.sources = [source] }",
    "params": {
      "source": doc.source
    }
  },
  "upsert": {
    "email": doc.email,
    "sources": [doc.source]
  }
}
```

but still no luck. Any help ?

Comment: What error does it yield when you run it?

Comment: If the document doesn't exist and you want your script to be able to create it, you need to add the parameter [`scripted_upsert: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_literal_scripted_upsert_literal) as well at the top level of your query.

Comment: its not giving any error. Also, when the document does not exist, it just uses the document in `upsert` to create a new entry. The problem I am facing is when the document already exists. It is not getting updated

Comment: What does `doc.source` refer to in your params? There doesn't seem to be any field named `source` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Scripting needs to be enabled to run scripts like this:

in the `elasticsearch.yml` file in config, add the following lines:

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

Comment: Doh! Good catch. Still not clear what `doc.source` refers to, though.

Comment: doc is a variable which stores an object. Example `{ "source": 2, "email": "aaa@bbb.com" }`

Comment: Yes, but in your original question, there was no `doc.source` field. All good now. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with that. Sorry for the confusion. I updated the question shortly after posting